# Haml Coffee Assets Template Error, no access to Backbone JS model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, coffeescript, haml, hamlc

I'm using haml_coffee_assets in a Rails 3.2 application. The following works in an ejs template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% tutorials.each(function(model) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= model.escape('title') %>
    </tr>
  <% }); %>
</table>
```

I can't seem to get this working in haml_coffee. The following was my best guess but for some reason this haml_coffee template doesn't work:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Tutorial Name
  %tbody
    - for tutorial in @tutorials
      - do (model) ->
      %tr
        %td= model.title
```

All I get with this is:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: model
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've mentioned that you're using Backbone on a GitHub issue, I assume that `@tutorials` is a Backbone collection and you can use also this alternative:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Tutorial Name
  %tbody
    - for model in @tutorials.models
      %tr
        %td= model.escape('title')
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'll update the question to include Backbone JS. This is great.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get this working with the following:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Tutorial Name
  %tbody
    - @tutorials.each (model) ->
      %tr
        %td= model.escape('title')
```

Hope this helps someone else!